# Network Monitoring System

Tags: system-monitor

I'm looking for a network monitoring system with these requirements. So far we tested *Icinga* but it didn't work well on our 32 inch:

- Freeware/GPL
- Monitor Linux/Windows
- Good for 32 inch display
- Switches be able to send alerts by email

Comment: Those seem to me like customized specs. Try [Nagios](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/nagios.html) it could help you a little

Answer (score 2):

One tool to the list [Anturis](http://www.anturis.com), a cloud-based tool to monitor the company network. It lets you to monitor

- Use ICMP Ping to check routes within your LAN or WAN.
- Check open ports (with a TCP monitor) to make sure network services are running and accessible.
- HTTP, SMTP, IMAP, POP3, SSL, FTP, SSH services monitoring.
  Here are only a few details of the tool.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with check_mk monitoring for almost two years.

I recommend you to install Open Monitoring Distribution - OMD (which packages Nagios, Check_mk, Nagvis and etc. together) with Check_mk. In Nagios, you need to monitor the services and hosts through the CLI Commands and edits. Also for just adding a host or services, you need to be expert in CLI. In Check_mk, everything will be provided in the GUI. It has a lot of features such as notification, WhatsApp notification, escalated notification for each team and etc.

1. Download the latest version of check_mk which comes with OMD ([Installation Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-open-monitoring-distribution-with-check_mk-on-ubuntu-14-04)).
2. Replace the downloading package mentioned in [this link](https://mathias-kettner.de/check_mk_download_version.php?HTML=yes&version=1.4.0p5&edition=cre) with below packages according to your Ubuntu version and code (command to find code - `lsb_release --all`)
3. Installation steps are very easy if you go with dpkg package.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i $packagename.deb$ # package installation
   sudo apt-get -f install # decencies installation
   sudo omd create montior
   ```

   The admin user for the web applications is `cmkadmin` with a random password. This random password can be seen in the session after creating your monitor. It can be changed with `htpasswd -m ~/etc/htpasswd cmkadmin` as site user.
4. Now proceed in the browser: `http://IP-ADDRESS/monitor`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Could you [edit] your answer and provide a bit more info (like how to install the software you're talking about?) also read [How do i write a good answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I hope the above provide guidelines are enough for installation of Check_mk package.Thanks Fabby

Comment: Much better! Upvoted (and thanks @muru for the edits as well)...

Answer (score 1):

With a quick search on the internet I was able to find these programs that may suit your requirements:

- Nagios (http://www.nagios.org/)
- Check_MK-Project (http://mathias-kettner.com/check_mk.html)
- Zabbix (http://www.zabbix.com/)
- OpenNMS (http://www.opennms.org/)
- Zenoss (http://www.zenoss.org/)
- Cacti (http://www.cacti.net/index.php)